# RaiseEvent does not fire custom RoutedEvent

Tags: c#, wpf

This is my first attempt to define my own RoutedEvent. When I debug this project, the OnMouseMove is reached as soon as I hover over the ellipse shape, **but RaiseEvent does nothing**. It's not even possible to step into RaiseEvent to see what's wrong (debugger just steps over).

**Control:**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

namespace TestTrailer2
{
    public class Trailer2: Control
    {
        public static readonly RoutedEvent DragDeltaEvent;

        public event DragDeltaEventHandler DragDelta 
        {
            add {AddHandler(Trailer2.DragDeltaEvent, value);}
            remove {RemoveHandler(Trailer2.DragDeltaEvent, value);}
        }

        static Trailer2()
        {
            Trailer2.DragDeltaEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("DragDelta", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(DragDeltaEventHandler), typeof(Trailer2));
        }

        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseMove(e);
            RaiseEvent(new DragDeltaEventArgs(0, 0));
        }
    }
}
```

**Code behind:**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace TestTrailer2
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void Trailer2_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

**Markup:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestTrailer2.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestTrailer2"
    Title="TestTrailer2" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Trailer2}">
            <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Trailer2}">
                    <Ellipse Width="100" Height="100" Fill="#AAD0D0DD"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <local:Trailer2 DragDelta="Trailer2_DragDelta">
    </local:Trailer2>
</Window>
```

Comment: Are you [raising it correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10144826/1997232)? I haven't done it myself, but it seems you have to pass parameter, which identify routed event, using one of overloads of [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms587938(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Sinatr: I will try it. But the framework (Thumb control) does it exactly the same way as I do above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you are reusing `DragDeltaEventArgs` which originally belong to another routed event, `Thumb.DragDeltaEvent`. So when you do:

```
RaiseEvent(new DragDeltaEventArgs(0, 0));
```

What really is being raised is `Thumb.DragDeltaEvent`, not your custom event (note that you don't state which event to raise anywhere). That event is hardcoded in `DragDeltaEventArgs` constructor.

If you want to continue reusing it - you need to state your custom event explicitly:

```
var args = new DragDeltaEventArgs(0, 0);
// this is event being raised,
// by default for this routed args its `Thumb.DragDeltaEvent`
args.RoutedEvent = Trailer2.DragDeltaEvent;
RaiseEvent(args);
```

Or just use custom routed event args.

Comment: Aaaah, I have missed that DragDeltaEventArgs actually makes one reference to Thumb! At first glance it looked just like an innocent class with nothing special in it. Tricky...

Comment: Thank you so much. It works now. It's hard to believe that I hoped for RaiseEvent to do its job without telling it which event to raise!!! :-)))